# Modal with centered title and right aligned close/X button

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I recently picked up Flutter and Dart and am  attempting to create an app that has a modal with three parts: a header, actual content, and a footer.

For the header I am looking to add a title (`Text`) center aligned and a close button right aligned.

I have the following code:

```dart
    Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  "Filters",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Visually, this looks like so:

[image: Result]

At a glance this looks fine but if you stare at it for a bit it doesn't. The "Filters" title isn't actually centered because (I assume) of the width of the X-button. I am struggling to figure out how to deal with this.

What is the proper way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add empty `SizedBox` with `width` as much as `IconButton` takes, try this:

```
Row(
    children: [
      SizedBox(
        width: width: 24 +
                8 +
                8, // the default size of icon + two default horizontal padding for IconButton
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Text(
          "Filters",
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 25,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
      IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

or you can add on other `IconButton` with `opacity 0` to hide the button and make title center, like this:

```
Row(
    children: [
      Opacity(
            opacity: 0,
            child: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {},
         ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Text(
          "Filters",
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 25,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
      IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Stack` and avoid hiding a button.

```
SizedBox(
  width: double.infinity,
  child: Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: [
      Positioned(
        right: 0,
        child: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: const Text(
          "Filters",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 25,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```